# How to perform interaction of two columns of a DF without permutations in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data.frame in R which has values for pairs of regions. The first columns can be constructed with the code:

```
region.1 <- c("SE", "SE", "SW", "S", "SW")
region.2 <- c("SW",  "S", "SE", "SE", "SE")
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(1,3,2,4,1)

df <- data.frame(x,y,region.1,region.2)
```

I would like to make a plot with different collors for each pair of regions, so I have tried

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
    geom_point(size=5,aes(color=interaction(region.1,region.2)))
```

However, the result wasn't what I was expecting, once the permutations of the same interaction were considered.

[image]

[As shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr1bD.png) there is the group SW.SE and SE.SW, for instance.

I would like to ask how could I make, in an inteligent way, groups of the pairs without the permutations.

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the plot you linked to. The point at `x = 5` corresponds to `y = 3` if you run your code, but `y = 1` in the linked plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two `dplyr`-based options. Both involve sorting the values of the two regions for each (x,y) pair. The first uses `mutate` to paste sorted values, done with `rowwise`. The second uses `gather` to make a single column of regions, arrange by pairs of (x,y), and then `summarise`s the regions by pasting them together.

```r
library(tidyverse)
region.1 <- c("SE", "SE", "SW", "S", "SW")
region.2 <- c("SW",  "S", "SE", "SE", "SE")
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(1,3,2,4,1)

df <- data.frame(x,y,region.1,region.2)

df_interact1 <- df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(interact = sort(c(region.1, region.2)) %>% paste(., collapse = ".")) %>%
  ungroup()


df_interact1
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>       x     y region.1 region.2 interact
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1     1     1 SE       SW       SE.SW   
#> 2     2     3 SE       S        S.SE    
#> 3     3     2 SW       SE       SE.SW   
#> 4     4     4 S        SE       S.SE    
#> 5     5     1 SW       SE       SE.SW

ggplot(df_interact1, aes(x = x, y = y, color = interact)) +
  geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

```r
df_interact2 <- df %>%
  gather(key = region, value = value, region.1, region.2) %>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  arrange(value) %>%
  summarise(interact = paste(min(value), max(value), sep = ".")) %>%
  ungroup()

df_interact2
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>       x     y interact
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1     1     1 SE.SW   
#> 2     2     3 S.SE    
#> 3     3     2 SE.SW   
#> 4     4     4 S.SE    
#> 5     5     1 SE.SW

ggplot(df_interact2, aes(x = x, y = y, color = interact)) +
  geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

Using your example data you can `apply` over the rows and then `sort` the regions and then `collapse` them into an interaction term as follows:

```
df$interaction <- apply(df, 1, function(x){paste(sort(c(x[3],x[4])), collapse = ".")})
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point(size=5,aes(color=interaction))
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above works properly, based on then I found a faster solution where one does not need to know the indexes on the data-frame, based on mutate, and paste. An ifelse is used to chose the order:

```
library(dplyr)
df<-df %>% mutate (
           region.1=as.character(region.1),
           region.2=as.character(region.2),
           interact = ifelse(region.1<region.2,
                                paste(region.1,region.2,sep="."),
                                paste(region.2,region.1,sep=".")))
```